# Call to undefined method Fuel\Core\Validation::errors()

Tags: php, fuelphp

i'm having problem when i want to validate my form in fuelphp framework

this is my code in controller

```
  /*
   * for getting request param for client and save to database
   */
  public function action_input(){
     $data = array();
     //checking method from client
     if(Input::method() == 'POST'){
        $val = Validation::forge();
        $val->add('name','Name')
           ->add_rule('required');
        $val->add('age','Age')
           ->add_rule('required');
        $val->add('alamat','Alamat')
           ->add_rule('required');
        $val->add('email', 'Email address')->add_rule('match_value', 'msofyancs@gmail.com', true)->add_rule('valid_email');

        if($val->run()){
           $data['name'] = Input::post('name');
           $data['body'] = Input::post('age');
           $data['alamat'] = Input::post('alamat');
           $data['email'] = Input::post('email');
        }else{
           $data['error'] = $val->errors('name')->get_message('The field :label must be filled out before auth is attempted.');
        } 
      return View::forge('testing/result', $data); 
     }
  }
```

if i'm input with validate is true(all field is correct) that is not problem, but when any field is not correct i have the error like this

```
ErrorException [ Error ]: Call to undefined method Fuel\Core\Validation::errors()
```

and debugger pointing to this code

```
$data['error'] = $val->errors('name')->get_message('The field :label must be filled out before auth is attempted.');
```

i don't know what happend, but i'm still declare $val in top of statement but the error is undefined, any someone is know?.

i'm new in fuelPHP framework, maybe you can give me suggestion how to validate form in fuelphp framework like better...thanks for your answer.

Comment: There is no `errors` method in `Fuel\Core\Validation` class, you could check the source :)

Comment: yes, i think so, but i'm still confuse i'm following [this documentation](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/validation/validation.html#config) and that is have $val->errors();

Comment: the errors() method was deprecated as of v1.1, and removed in v1.2. This reference was forgotten when the docs were updated. This has now been corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/validation/validation.html#config):

```
// get an array of validation errors as field => error pairs
$errors = $val->error();
```